# Run-time Error 7: Out of Memory in vba - excel file 139KB and 80KB and 90 lines macro

Tags: excel, vba, out-of-memory

I would be very grateful if anybody could help me to optimize my macro. I can't see a problem in it, the most memory demanding part is setting a range into variable which consists of 18x5 cells array.

Attached is screen from Variant[image]

The excel files that I'm working on are 130KB and 80KB.

So it's hard for me to believe that it in fact is out of memory. Maybe I have some leak that I'm not seeing. Please look at the attached code:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetRangeNames(ByRef wb As Workbook) As String
  Dim cmdSet As String
  Dim nm As Object
  For Each nm In wb.Names
    If nm.Name Like Chr(42) & "info_" & Chr(42) Or _
       nm.Name Like Chr(42) & "timer_" & Chr(42) Then
        cmdSet = cmdSet & "If RangeExists(""" & nm.Name & """) Then ActiveWorkbook.Names(""" & nm.Name & """).Delete" & vbCrLf
        cmdSet = cmdSet & "ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=""" & nm.Name & """, RefersTo:=""" & nm.RefersTo & """" & vbCrLf
    End If
  Next nm
  Set nm = Nothing
  GetRangeNames = cmdSet
End Function


Sub StringExecute(s As String)
    Dim vbComp As Object
    Set vbComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    vbComp.CodeModule.AddFromString _
        "Function RangeExists(R As String) As Boolean" & vbCrLf _
        & "Dim Test As Range" & vbCrLf _
        & "On Error Resume Next" & vbCrLf _
        & "Set Test = ActiveSheet.Range(R)" & vbCrLf _
        & "RangeExists = Err.Number = 0" & vbCrLf _
        & "End Function" & vbCrLf _
        & "Sub foo()" & vbCrLf _
        & s & vbCrLf _
        & "End Sub"
    Application.Run vbComp.Name & ".foo"
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbComp
End Sub


Sub prosjekt_oppdateringer()

' ------------ INIT --------------
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Dim namesCmdSet As String
  Dim copyRange As Variant


' ------------ UPDATE LEVERANSE-DATA TABLE --------------
  Sheets("leveranse-data").Select
  If Range("Z1").Value <> "Tid etter leverandør" Then
    Columns("Z:Z").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("tab_leveranse_data[[#Headers],[Kolonne1]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OB"
    Columns("Z:Z").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("tab_leveranse_data[[#Headers],[Kolonne1]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Tid etter leverandør"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  End If


' ------------ UPDATE EPOST TABLE --------------
  Sheets("prosjekt-info").Select
  Range("tab_eposter").Select

  Application.Workbooks.Open _
    Filename:="!prosjekt.xlsx", _
    Local:=True

  copyRange = Range("tab_eposter").Formula2Local
  namesCmdSet = GetRangeNames(ActiveWorkbook)

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ActiveWindow.Close False

  StringExecute (namesCmdSet)
  namesCmdSet = ""

  Range("tab_eposter").Value = copyRange ' <--- this is a part where I get Out of memory error.

  Sheets("prosjekt-info").Select
  Range("D3").Select



' ------------ DE-INIT --------------
'  ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
'  Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Comment: It's not clear why you need to dynamically insert code into your project?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm maintaining an excel template for projects and I need a macro that will update the old project files created from older versions of the template.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for seeing my post.

I have found solution to my question:
I did have formulas copied so I couldn't insert it as Values because of the equal sign in the beginning of the variant variable.

```
    copyRange = Range("tab_eposter").Formula2Local
```

The solution that works for me is:

```
    Range("tab_eposter").Formula2Local = copyRange
```

But it also doesn't work as it should so I had to use loop through every cell in range, but eventually made it.

The strange thing is that this Value / Formula did throw out Out of Memory error.